# MSSQL Data and Log file Clarification

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

We need to implement a strategy for improving our SQL Server database performance and I am investigating the topic of Data (mdf) and Transaction Log (ldf) files.  There is quite a lot of information if I google but some slight differences in guidance.  Can I ask the following clarification questions

1. If I have both data files and log files on same drive

   a) Performance is affected due to the different write president on log files over data
   files?

   b) If drive is totally corrupted then everything since last
   backup is lost completely?
2. If I have data file and log file on different drives

   a) Does this have to be just different drives in virtual server, a different physical
   drive on the same host server that is hosting numerous virtual servers or in
   a completely different host server machine?

   b) If data file drive becomes corrupted then database becomes Read-only and transactions
   from time of last backup and time of corruption can be restored from
   log file using a Tail-Log Backup?

   c) If logical file drive becomes corrupted then database becomes Read-only and transactions
   since last backup are lost completely?

Comment: It would be incredibly rare these days for real performance problems to be due to how you have arranged log and data files assuming you're using modern storage hardware (SSDs, SANs etc). If you have a performance problem then the first thing you should do is find out what the source of the problem is (usually this means identifying the slow SQL and looking at the actual execution plan to see where the time is going), working through checklists is not the way unless you're a consultant being paid by the hour.

Comment: 1a) It depends - really, it depends on the storage solution being used.  1b) If you lose both data and log files - regardless of where they are located, then you recover by restoring the latest backup and all tlog backups available up to the current point in time.  Which should be stored in a location that is not local to that server.  If you don't have tlog backups then - yes, you lose data from the last restorable backup forward.

Comment: @Jeff - thanks.  This helps.  I believe we are using SSD's on the virtual server hosting machines, so having both MDF and LDF on same location should not be affected. I understand thanks.  Regarding Tail-Log backups, these should be created and stored in a completely different physical location as these are the MOST CRUCIAL - is that correct?

Comment: @AndrewSayer - thanks Andrew.  It is SSD on the virtual server hosting machines yes.  So that is not an issue.  No, I am not a contractor, but not a DBA either and just trying to figure out how to improve performance and disaster recovery improvements